# Why do I get “ stray '#' in program ” error?

Tags: arduino-ide

I am making an Arduino program with SIM800L module and would like to check credit status of the SIM card.
When I manually enter the command: AT+CUSD=1,"*123#" into Serial Monitor, it works fine.

But in the Arduino (1.8.7) I am receiving an error 
      `stray  "#" in program`

when compiling this line of sketch:
      `SIM800.print("AT+CUSD=1,"*123#"\r");`

I am not experienced enough to fix this problem.
Could somebody help me, please?

Thank you.
Marko

Comment: I think something else is stray. Why are there three double quotes in "*123#"\r". A backslash is a normal part of a string, why did you put it outside the string?

Comment: There are four quotes in the command ("AT+CUSD=1,"*123#"\r"). When I manually enter this command into Serial Monitor, I type  AT+CUSD=1,"*123#" .

Comment: Sorry, there are four indeed. A double quote " in a string closes the string. You need the escape backslash and use \" in the same way as the escape is used for \r. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape

Comment: I understand that  *123#  is a string for provider to perform this function (return a info of my SIM credit). When I make a phone call from my mobitel, I just enter *123# and receive an answer with this info.

Comment: It is interesting that a similar command:    SIM800.print("ATD*123#\r");   works fine ( return OK) and without any compiler comment.

Answer (score 3):

Use the escape backslash to get a double quote in a text. See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape

Is the `*123$` between double quotes?

```
Serial.println("Hello");
Serial.println("I said: Hello to you");
Serial.println("I said: \"Hello\" to you");
Serial.println("AT+CUSD=1,\"*123#\"\r");
Serial.println("AT+CUSD=1,\"*123#\"");
```

I think the carriage return `\r` at the end is not needed when the `println` is used. The `println` adds a linefeed `\n` by the way.

Comment: The last suggested command   SIM800.println("AT+CUSD=1,\"*123#\"");  is accepted by compiler but returns only "OK" - the same answer as basic command  SIM800.println("AT+CUSD=1"); . It looks like as the parameter \"*123#\  is not forwarded to SIM800?

Comment: .....or the provider does not recognise this parameter \"*123#\  ?

Comment: You could try to send the ASCII code of these characters with Serial.write(). In that way you don't have to bother about escaping and the compiler doesn't see the # anymore.

Comment: The command \"*123#\" is translated by the compiler into "*123#" including the two double quotes. I don't know if that is recognized, I see examples that have a comma and a number after it.

Comment: Thank you all for the good will and your efforts to help me. Jot, can you please clarify what is meant by "... have a comma and a number after it."

Comment: For example AT+CUSD=1,"*123#",15 You should use the sim800 commands. On Github are arduino libraries for the sim800 that you can use (or use as an example).